# What's wrong with this nginx configuration(error_page)?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have configuration:

```
server {
        server_name "mysite.ru";
        root "/var/www/mysite/";

        ###
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
       }



        #Errors
        error_page 400 /errors/index.php?400;
        error_page 403 /errors/index.php?403;
        error_page 404 /errors/index.php?404;
        error_page 500 /errors/index.php?500;

        location = /errors/ {
                root "/var/www/common";
                internal;
        }

}
```

But it still showing default nginx 404 error page.

Comment: What does your nginx log say?

Comment: @EEAA nothing. error.log and access.log are both empty

Comment: @EEAA i looked again in access.log: `myip - - [19/Dec/2015:19:16:42 +0300] "GET /testest2fsdf HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are attempting to execute a php script from within a different root. Your exact match location will only match the URI `/errors/` and not `/errors/index.php`. However, even if it did match the URI, it cannot execute PHP scripts at that location.

You need to replicate your `fastcgi` directives within any location that is expected to execute a PHP script. For example:

```
location = /errors/index.php {
    root "/var/www/common";
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    internal;
}
```